# What did Griffin show the Colonel to convince him in Men in Black 3?

Tags: plot-explanation, men-in-black-3

I'm wondering what exactly is shown to the Colonel by Griffin near the end of Men in Black 3 (MIB3)?

I don't remember exactly what the Colonel answered when J asked him what he saw, but it was pretty vague.

Any ideas?

Comment: He COULD also have been shown that J is the man his son grows up to become... Or, not. (considering there wasn't any maudlin emotional stuff going on there...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

He answers with

> He showed me how important you are... you and your partner.

So my interpretation is he showed him **the truth** about J, J's future and his mission:

> Young Agent K: You ever wanna see more, I know a top secret organization that can use a man like you.
>
> Colonel: I wish I could.

Here I have the impression that Colonel has also seen his own death.

Comment: Ohh nice ! I didn't notice the last line of the Colonel. I agree that this could be an interesting clue.

Answer (score 7):

The film seemed to imply that he was shown clips from J's life; notice that he says J, specifically, is "important", then hastily amends that to being the pair of them. Similarly, he was probably aware that his death is what caused J to grow up as he had, since, as Guy pointed out, he seems aware of his own death.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can recall he said "He showed me how important you were."  I'm guessing that he was shown what would happen if J and K weren't allowed to put the Arc Net on the ship.

Answer (score 0):

He obviously showed the man that agent J was his son and that he will die, also that agent k will look over him and that he was going to die.

Also agent k(young) soon realises as well who agent J is